# "Fixed Domains" of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, functional-analysis, self-learning, eigenfunctions

Given a linear transformation $T$, I need to find the set of all domains $D$ such that $T:D\mapsto D$. Equivalently, I need to find the set of all domains $D$ that are symmetric under $T$.

Aside from solving this particular question, what sort of theory should I study to solve this sort of question?

Comment: By domain, you just mean subset, right? Do you require $T(D) = D$ or is $T(D) \subset D$ good enough?

Comment: No, I need equality. In context, I need to find the set of all functions $f:D \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $Tf=f$, or ideally prove that no such functions exist (in the context in which I'm working), and I thought a good first step would be identifying the domain $D$ on which such a function must be defined.

Comment: Wait.  You seem to be describing two different questions in the original question vs. your comment.

Comment: Right. First, in retrospect even if I had the set of all $f$ the first thing I'd do is find the union of their domains anyway; second, like I said, I need the answer to this as an intermediate result and it's what my actual question is for now. I might post the original as a separate question if I have trouble making the jump.

Comment: The question remains unclear. On what space does the transformation $T$ act?

Comment: @PostNoBills That is precisely the question. (In general, we have $D\in\mathbb{R}^n$, but the point is to find $D$ s.t $TD=D$, that is, $\forall x\in D$, $\exists y\in D:Tx=y$ and $\forall y\in D$, $\exists x\in D: Tx=y$.

Comment: Oh, wait, I see what you're saying. $T:S\mapsto U$ for some $S,U$, and obviously $S\cap U=\emptyset\implies D=\emptyset$. Basically the specific domains shouldn't matter for the problem. (The particular application has $S=U=\mathbb{R}^n$ for some integer $n$.)